# error CS0104: 'EntityState' and I have framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting these errors:

> error CS0104: 'EntityState' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Data.EntityState' and 'System.Data.Entity.EntityState'
>
> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.EntityState' to 'System.Data.Entity.EntityState'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

And the culprit is on this line:

```
context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified; (EntityState.Modified being the error.
```

The second error in particular I am surprised about because I already performed the instructions in this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/upgradeEF6

Yet, I am still getting this problem with `EntityState`.

Could somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using both namespaces `System.Data` and `System.Data.Entity`, they both have a property called `EntityState` so the compiler can't decide which to use. In these cases you need to use full namespace references, like `System.Data.Entity.EntityState`, or use namespace aliasing: `using akaEntity = System.Data.Entity;` and then access the property by `akaEntity.EntityState`.

Answer (score 0):

Does cleaning the whole solution and then rebuilding help?  I suspect you've got an old reference in a bin directory that hasn't been removed.

You'll probably find the two `EntityState`(s) don't point to the same assembly.  Find out the EntityFramework assembly they refer to and you may find that one of the assemblies can be manually deleted.

Comment: Found out what it was. Had to replace EntityState.Modified with System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified. Thank you for your input though.